# What's the difference between --skip-stylesheets and --no-stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I wanted to generate scaffold without stylesheets, and I found these two flags: `--skip-stylesheets`, `--no-stylesheets`. What's the difference between them?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did the answer below help you in any way?

Answer (score 5):

If you run `rails g scaffold --help`, it will show help information for that generator along with a list of options.

Some of the options have default values. For example, if you look at

```
-y, [--stylesheets]                           # Generate Stylesheets
                                              # Default: true
```

You see it defaults to true. If you don't want to generate stylesheets, you can prefix the option with `--no` to disable that specific option.

The `skip-stylesheets` option is defined in the [Runtime options] section as follows:

```
-s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
```

**So to answer your question:**

`--no-stylesheets` doesn't generate stylesheets at all

`--skip-stylesheets` generates stylesheets but skips the ones that already exist.